# How to prevent predicate to fetching relationship objects?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have one entity which has one to many relationship with another entity. I am facing the problem in fetching data.

I want to prevent the fetching relationship objects to reduce memory overhead.

let me know if there is any way for this.

Comment: What issue you are facing? Are you not being able to fetch source entity objects?

Comment: related objects should be fetched as faults so there should be minimal memory impact.

Comment: Actually objects of a relationship don't need to be (re)fetched.

Comment: In other words, the optimization you want is already built into Core Data.